# Disable clicks during a powerpoint animation

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, microsoft-office-2016

I have a powerpoint slide with some animations that happen straight away, then some chained follow-on animations on click.

The problem is, if someone clicks during the first second while the first lot of animations are still happening, the chain messes up - things that fade in never appear, things resize from the wrong size, etc etc.

How can I disable the click event that starts the second set of animations until the first set of animations has completed?

I've tried putting a delay on the animation with the click event, but that just delays the animation *after* the click event, rather than delaying when the click event can be registered.

Answer (score 1):

**Use a Button as a Layer:**

You can't disable PowerPoint mouse functions. But as a cheap trick, you can insert a transparent button that fills the screen and does nothing but absorbing user's clicks.

- Choose the slide you want to disable user's clicks.
- From the Ribbon, go to `INSERT` \ `Shapes`. Grouped under `Action Button`, use the `Action Button: Custom` to draw a shape that covers the entire slide.
- Right after drawing the button, the dialogue box `Action Settings` pops up. Choose `None` in both tabs `Mouse click` and `Mouse over`. Then `Ok`.
- Select the button/shape that you inserted and from the Ribbon tab `Home`, assign `No fill` from button `Shape fill` and `No outline` from button `Shape Outline`.

**Pros:**

Does what you wanted.

**Cons:**

- While editing, the button will cover the other objects so you'll need to put the button aside if you want to access them.
- Only applicable to one slide; you'll have to copy and paste the button on other slides that should be having the same effect.